How to query on multiple queries in KDB+?
In KDB+, I have multiple tables in tables[] that have the same name prefix. For example, I have 8 tables that start with the word 'users_'. The full name is something like 'users_1', 'users_2', etc.
I want to perform the following query:
```select regestration_date from tables[] where tables[] like "users_*"```

How can I get the same result since the query mentioned above is not working, I get type error.
Note: I do not want to perform join because number of tables are big and the tables have a lot of records, so the resulted table will be huge.
Thank you!

Easiest way to accomplish this is with a lambda and each.
raze {select regestration_date from x} each tables[] where tables[] like "users_*"

raze will collapse the individual outputs to a single table.

Hello Thomas. Thank you for your answer!
I'm getting this result: (kx.c$Flip@29138086;kx.c$Flip@29692c1b)

It worked! I just added raze before. Thank you!

Good stuff, I have updated my answer to add raze.
